# Rails cache expire at midnight every day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to do something like

```
Rails.cache.fetch("id..", expire_in: 1.day, expire_at: midnight) do
  #...
end
```

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't an `expires_at` option, but you can quickly calculate the number of seconds between your desired expiration time and the current time. Assuming you mean "expire at the end of the day tomorrow", you could do something like this:

```
expires_in_seconds = Time.now.end_of_day + 1.day - Time.now
Rails.cache.fetch("id...", expires_in: expires_in_seconds) do
  #...
end
```

Where `expires_in_seconds` would return a number of seconds (e.g. `90559`)

If you just mean "end of today", it would be `Time.now.end_of_day - Time.now`.

Comment: why not just `Time.current.end_of_day - Time.current` ?

Comment: @montrealmike That would work fine for "today at midnight" but I thought you meant "tomorrow at midnight" (since you said both "expire in 1 day" and "expire at midnight")

Answer (score 0):

you can set expire time when you are creating it

Rails.cache.write("your key or id", expires_in: 1.day)

Answer (score 0):

Careful not to get a decimal, if you want an integer...

```
>_ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.2)
 >> Time.now.end_of_day + 1.day - Time.now
169207.001996682
 >> (Time.now.end_of_day + 1.day - Time.now).to_i
169204
 >>
```